# Running time calculation example

Tags: data-structures, big-o

I was going through the examples of Big Oh to calculate Running time calculation from Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis using C by mark Weiss.

The example is:

```
int sum(int N)
/*1*/ int sum=0;
/*2*/ for (int i=1;i<=N;i++)
/*3*/      sum=sum+i*i*i;
/*4*/      return sum;
```

I understand the cost for each line, but  I have confusion for the line no 2, that in line 2 there are three things, initialization, testing and increment. so the total cost for initialization is `1` and for testing `(n+1)` and n for all the increment. I want to know that how for testing the cost is `n+1` because from the condition, the loop will run `n` time then how the cost will be `n+1`?

Comment: I got it.. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say n=5. The condition will run 6 times and for 6th time the condition will not be true so n+1 testing.